# ¿Cómo ejecuto una petición http en un ciclo síncronamente?

Tags: nodejs, http, promesas, axios

Tengo una api básica con NodeJs y Express, lo que estoy intentado realizar es hacer múltiples inserciones dentro de un ciclo for, recorriendo un arreglo de clientes, por medio de una petición http utilizando la librería 'axios'.
Este es mi código:

```
function agregarClientes(){
    var array = [{nombre:"Cliente1", numero:123},{nombre:"Cliente2", numero:123}]
    array.forEach(cliente => {
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'http://test.com', 
            data: cliente,
        }).then(response => {

        }).catch(e => {

        })
    })
}
```

Necesito que no se realice la siguiente inserción hasta que la anterior haya finalizado.

Comment: ¿Que *se realice* o que *no se realice*?

Comment: No deberías ejecutar llamadas xhr (ajax) de manera síncrona, si no de manera consecutiva asíncronamente. ¿Cuál es el motivo por el que necesitas que se haga consecutivamente? ¿El usuario pulsa varias veces o porque tu aplicación realiza dos altas?

Comment: then(response => {, Ejecuta aquí la siguiente llamada y así ...

Comment: Que no se realice la siguiente inserción hasta haber concluido la anterior @PabloLozano

Comment: En tu caso yo implementaría la lógica de la inserción de clientes del lado servidor. Enviar una petición `http` por cada elemento de tu `array` no es para nada eficiente. En cambio si envías una sola petición enviando tu `array` de datos y ejecutas la inserción en serie en el lado servidor seguro es más eficiente. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías usar Async/Await para poder manipular las Promises de manera sincrónica:

```
const agregarClientes = () => {
  const array = [
    { nombre: 'Cliente1', numero: 123 },
    { nombre: 'Cliente2', numero: 123 }
  ];
  array.forEach(async cliente => {
    try {
      await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://test.com',
        data: cliente
      })
    } catch (e) {
      // catch error
    }
    // success
  });
}
```

Comment: En el último comentario, el OP indica que requiere realizar las operaciones de tal manera que cada nueva inserción (o solicitud `POST`) no se realice hasta que la anterior haya finalizado. Tu respuesta sugiere usar `Promise.all()`, la cual ejecutará las llamadas en *paralelo* y no en *serie* como pide el OP. Revisa un poco tu respuesta. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras no había leído el comentario, ahora modifico la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, buena aportación.